# How to set row height of QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt, row, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I have `QTableView` and `QAbstractTableModel`. I require rows to have height equal to 24. I know the only way to do this is by calling `QTableView::setRowHeight`. Since the model is dynamic it may be added new rows, but I don't want to call `setRowHeight` each time new row is added.

How can I configure `QTableView` such that it uses the same height for new added rows or can a model be sent the height of rows?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

For **Qt versions < 5**

```
QHeaderView *verticalHeader = myTableView->verticalHeader();
verticalHeader->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::Fixed);
verticalHeader->setDefaultSectionSize(24);
```

For **Qt versions >= 5** use

```
QHeaderView *verticalHeader = myTableView->verticalHeader();
verticalHeader->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Fixed);
verticalHeader->setDefaultSectionSize(24);
```

If that function doesn't apply to vertical headers, you likely will have to call `setRowHeight()` every time you add a new row.

Comment: I think it's better to give a name to the pointer different from the function name, otherwise you may have name conficts, e.g. if you do this from QTableView constructor    QHeaderView *vh = myTableView->verticalHeader();

Comment: If `verticalHeader` is already in scope, then just call `setResizeMode` and `setDefaultSectionSize` on it directly, no need to be worried about variable shadowing and no need to copy a local pointer.

Comment: `QHeaderView` bounds the value passed to `setDefaultSectionSize` so you might need to call `setMinimumSectionSize` and `setMaximumSectionSize` before setting the default size.